# How to save Activity Class as a variable to use it later in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, google-cloud-messaging

i'd like to know how can i store a class as a variable.

for example i'd like to store which activity to open-up when push notification is clicked,

for that i created a method which accepts a class with activity extension

```
final Class<? extends Activity> ActivityToOpen
```

what i want is use the saved Class for the intent of the push notification.

For example a method like `setLandingActivity(MainActivity.class);`

and in which i can retrieve and use it to give as parameter for my `showNotification` Method

new question based on the answer;

[Class for Name requires full path and cant find with just the class name - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479261/class-for-name-requires-full-path-and-cant-find-with-just-the-class-name-andro)

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Pass data between activities? Because this method of passing activities around is a very bad programming practice.

Comment: @GeorgeD what i want is creating a method which will take a activity as input and that given activity will be open as intent when the push notification clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store the class name as a String and then use

```
Class.forName(String)
```

Comment: barq hey man, is there anyway to get full path?

this method that you suggested takes argument like this Class.forName("com.example.test.secondproject.MainActivity")

but i wanted something like Class.forName("MainActivity") which will return error in this case,

How can i get full path of a class? to use it like this?

T

Comment: It should work for Class.forName("MainActivity") as well. Please open a new question with details of your error trace and post a link here so we can have a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479261/class-for-name-requires-full-path-and-cant-find-with-just-the-class-name-andro

Answer (score -1):

static variables holds value till application is running, once application get destroy all static variables **loses their references** (non long term) while share preference holds the value even if application get destroy, so consistency is more in share preference

now its upto you whether you want the variable value consistent or not