# Class for Name requires full path and cant find with just the class name - android

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to use `Class.forName()` method with just the name of my file.

In my case it's "MainActivity" But when I try to use it in a try catch block it cant find the Class with name of MainActivity, when i debugged, i found out that

`MainActivity.class.getName()` gives me **com.example.test.secondproject.MainActivity**

so i used it as my argument in `Class.forName("com.example.test.secondproject.MainActivity")` and it worked just fine,

how can I make it work with just Class.forName("MainActivity"), or is it an expected behavior

```
  try {
            Log.i(TAG,"try main activity ");            showNotification(context,intent.getStringExtra("message").toString(),Class.forName("MainActivity"));


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"try fail error: "+ e);

        }
```

this is the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainActivity

showNotification;

```
 public static void  showNotification(Context context,String message,final Class ActivityToOpen) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen), 0);



        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: Show more code of the context of what you are doing please.

Comment: If you have two classes - for example `one.MainActivity` and `two.MainActivity` - which one should the JRE select if simply asking with `Class.forName("MainActivity")`? In other words: This is expected behavior.

Comment: @barq all context added

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same package for all classes then you can set that as a constant and append to your class. Otherwise you will need to specify the whole package name.

Comment: is there a way to get full path from just the Class Name?

Like i have a variable called className

And a method which returns the full path getFullPath(String className)

Comment: YourClass.class.getPackage().getName();

Comment: well in that example i need to know my class aka YourClass, that needs to be a dynamic string

Comment: Then cut off the package name.

Comment: i wont know the package name until i have a class.

Thats where I'm struggling, I need to have the class from the given string.If i get the Class I can move from there. and in your example you assume to have the class - YourClass- , I have MyString not MyClass

Comment: I still don't understand what the underlying problem is. Maybe if you describe that it will be easier to find a solution. I don't think what you are currently attempting is the best solutionl

Comment: well the overall goal is, create a system to describe the landing page when user clicked the push notification.

As you can see in my showNotification method, it requires an activity class.In my first question i asked for a way to store that class to use it and pass as an argument and you said offer that classname method and here we are